# Get name of ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I can't get name of `ListView` item by click. I fill data from database with `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and when I click on item I want to get item name, but I recive data like this

`android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@4054b988`.

How I can get text from it?

There is m click listener:

```java
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object object = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String item = object.toString();
    Log.i( TAG, "Name: " + item );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting item name? Calling `toString()` will generate a String from its slot in memory. If you want to get the name of the Object then your Object should have a method to provide that its name, for example `getName()`

Comment: As you can see in my listener, I call toString() for object. Its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you got what you've called. Every object has a default `toString()` method which will return a String describe its class name and position in memory and that's the result you got there. You have to override this method to have a meaningful return value. For example, by casting `Object` to a meaningful object of your own

```
class Item{
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name; 
    }
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object object = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Item item = (Item) object;
    String name = item.getName() \\ or = item.toString(); it's the same
    Log.i( TAG, "Name: " + name );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line of code instead

```
String str = listDishes.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
```

where `listDishes` is the ListView that sets the adapter...